# DynamoDB update a field which has a JSON as value with integer/num-string as keys in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I am storing an item with the following structure in my dynamodb table.

```
Item = {"response": [
    {
        "answers": {
            "11-18": 0,
            "19-24": 0
        }
    }
]}
```

I want to update response[0].answers.11-18 incrementally.
My command was:

```
table_resource.update_item(
        Key={
            'id': 123
        },
        UpdateExpression="set response[0].answers.11-18 = response[0].answers.11-18 + :inc",
        ExpressionAttributeValues={":inc": 1},
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW",
)
```

I get the following error.

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: "11", near: ".11-"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your nested attribute `11-18` begins with a number, so you can’t use it in an update expression.

> If an attribute name begins with a number or contains a space, a special character, or a reserved word, then you must use an expression attribute name to replace that attribute's name in the expression.

You can work around this by using placeholder  [ExpressionAttributeNames](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html).

Comment: Would it create problems if the nested attribute did not begin with a number when I'm using an ExpressionAttributeName?

Comment: No. You can use safely use ExpressionAttributeNames for any or every attribute.